# NSNumber and NSFloat

Tags: iphone, ios, model-view-controller, floating-point, nsnumber

Why wont this output 5 to the console? It is outputting 0?!

settingsData.sensitivitySettingValue is an NSNumber defined in a model class.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    float five = 5;

    settingsData.sensitivitySettingValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:five];

    float someFloat = [settingsData.sensitivitySettingValue floatValue];

    NSLog(@"%f", someFloat);

}
```

Can't understand it!

Comment: add `NSLog (@"settingsData object: %@", settingsData);` to your logging and see if that actually is not nil;.

Comment: You might want to link to your previous question, as they're clearly connected... I already commented on your earlier question suggesting it could be a problem with your settingsData/sensitivitySettingValue setup...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll bet `settingsData` is nil, so when you send it the `sensitivitySettingValue` you get nil back, and when you send that nil the `floatValue`, you get nil back.

Comment: ah that sounds like it must be it. How do I resolve that? Sorry, complete newbie with model classes...